# Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::id()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I don't know what is wrong. I'm sure this is correct, but the server side is not processing.

**Controller**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('back.pages.home');
    }

    public function changeProfilePicture(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(auth('web')->id());
        $path = 'images/user/';
        $file = $request->file('cropImage');
        $old_picture = $user->getAttributes()['picture'];
        $file_path = $path.$old_picture;
        $new_image_name = 'CCSIMG'.$user->id().rand(1, 100000).'.jpg';
        if ($old_picture != null && File::exists(public_path($file_path))) {
            File::delete(public_path($file_path));
        }
        
        $upload = $file->move(public_path($path), $new_image_name);
        if ($upload) {
            $user->update([
                'picture' => $new_picture_new
            ]);
            
            return response()
                ->json(['status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your Profile Picture has been successfully updated.']);
        } else {
            return response()
                ->json(['status' => 0, 'Something went wrong, Please Try Again Later']);
        }
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware(['auth:web'])->group(function(){
        Route::get('/home',[UserController::class,'index'])->name('home');
        Route::post('/crop',[UserController::class,'changeProfilePicture'])->name('crop');
    });
});
```

How I call it from the URL jquery script

`processUrl:'{{ route("admin.crop") }}'`

I tried many methods, but it's not working.

Comment: `$user->id` is a parameter, not a function. Drop the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, please remove the parentheses after the id and then try running your code again. This change should help resolve the issue.

```
$new_image_name = 'CCSIMG'.$user->id.rand(1,100000).'.jpg';
```